# How can I programmatically create new Gnosis Safe?

Tags: contract-deployment, gnosis-safe

Is there documentation anywhere on how to create a gnosis safe programmatically with detailed information on how to construct parameters?

Here's what I tried in Remix (which i know is the incorrect approach):

1. Compiled+Deployed `GnosisSafe.sol`
2. Called the `setup` function with the following parameters:

```
["0xAb8483F64d9C6d1EcF9b849Ae677dD3315835cb2", "0x4B20993Bc481177ec7E8f571ceCaE8A9e22C02db"],1,0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000,"0x",0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000,0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000,0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000,0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

The error that I got:

```
The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Reason provided by the contract: "GS200".
```

So this fails because the contract threshold is set to 1 when I deploy `GnosisSafe.sol`. I think it's because I'm supposed to use `createProxyWithNonce` in `GnosisSafeProxyFactory.sol` to create a new safe.

But I'm not sure which contracts to deploy, and how to construct the parameters it expects (`_singleton`, `initializer`, `saltNonce`).

Help here would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You don’t need to deploy GnosisSafe.sol or proxy factory. There are already singletons deployed. You can check the addresses here: https://github.com/safe-global/safe-deployments/tree/main/src/assets/v1.3.0

You can check unit tests here:
https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/v1.3.0/test/factory/ProxyFactory.spec.ts
https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/v1.3.0/test/core/GnosisSafe.Setup.spec.ts